# Program works with string literals but not with string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, hashtable

I have a hashtable ADT which has two functions, insert and lookup. I put in to the insert function a hash table, hash table size, ID #, and book title and that inserts it into the hash table. This works fine when I pass it a string literal, i.e. `insert(...,"Hello, world!"...);` It doesn't work when I read in strings from a file, store them in an array, and try and use my insert and lookup functions.
I have all of my code here but the most important files are main.c and hash.c. Hash.c has the newHash(), hash(), insert(), and lookup() functions and main.c reads from two files, in this case test1.lib.in and test1.req.in, and from the first file will get the library id and title of a book from each line and then put it in the hash table. From the second file, it gets requests for a book title and should print the ids in its linked list.

- **List of links to files** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tFNs-eVkfnCfjwAHcAUdHtUl1KVv_WcnW2IS0SRFvcM/edit?usp=sharing

Example of code that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "hash.h"

int main(){
    ListHndl* temp = newHash(10);
    insert(442440, "cvyaqbznxel", 10,temp);
    lookup(temp,"cvyaqbznxel", 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Code that doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "hash.h"


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Incorrect arguments, please specify 2 files to be read\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    FILE *secondFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (file == 0 || secondFile == 0) {
        printf("Could not open a file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int numDataLines2;
    int numDataLines;
    int hashTableSize;
    //First line of first file gives number of lines in file and 
    //size of hash table to be made
    if(fscanf(file, "%d%d", &numDataLines, &hashTableSize) < 2) {
        printf("Unable to parse first line of first file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    ListHndl* theHash = newHash(hashTableSize);
    int libraryID;
    char *tempString = calloc(numDataLines,41*sizeof(char));
    char lineHolder[129];
    //discard the new line which always shows up
    fgets(lineHolder, 128, file);
    for(int i = 0; i < numDataLines; i++) {
        //Gets the whole line to be scanned with sscanf
        fgets(lineHolder, 128, file);

        //If the line consists of just a newline char, continue
        if(strcmp(lineHolder, "\n") == 0 ) {
            continue;
        }
        //Scans the line retrieved from fgets and placed in lineHolder
        if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%d, %40[^\n]", &libraryID,&tempString[i]) == 0){
            printf("Unable to parse line %d of first file\n",i+2);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        insert(libraryID, &tempString[i], hashTableSize, theHash);
    }
    char String[41];
    fgets(String, 40, secondFile);
    numDataLines2 = atoi(String);
    char *storeSecondFileStuff = calloc(numDataLines2,41*sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i< numDataLines2; i++) {
        fgets(lineHolder, 128, secondFile);
        if(strcmp(lineHolder, "\n") == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%40[^\n]",&storeSecondFileStuff[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Unable to parse line %d of second file\n",i+2);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        lookup(theHash, &storeSecondFileStuff[i], hashTableSize);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(file);
    fclose(secondFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: it would be so much easier for all of us, if you didn't try to tell a story about your code, but actually showed us

Comment: I put a link which contains all of my code. Need me to elaborate on something?

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/428

Comment: ALSO: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: I edited some code in, it doesn't compile because it requires various files which feel like too much to paste here but I think the gist of the program is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple problems. To start with, you might not be scanning your input line correctly. Change your line

```
 if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%d, %40[^\n]", &libraryID,&tempString[i]) == 0)
```

to

```
 if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%d, %40[^\n]", &libraryID, tempString) < 0)
```

that way, you will trap the situation where the `sscanf` function did not successfully convert both arguments - for example, if there is no comma in the input line. Note that `sscanf` returns the number of successful conversions; success would return a value of `2`, so testing for `<2` is the right way to go.

Note also that I changed `&tempString[i]` to `tempString`. The former points to some place along `tempString` - which only has 41 characters allocated to it. Yet you always allow up to 40 characters (plus `'\0'` to be written to it - so you will write past the end of the string. Since this is only a temporary variable, there is no sense in doing this. Just scan the input into the temp variable, then do whatever you need to do with it.

This means that your `insert` also changes, from

```
    insert(libraryID, &tempString[i], hashTableSize, theHash);
```

to

```
    insert(libraryID, tempString, hashTableSize, theHash);
```

Again, you need to do the same thing lower down in your code.

Here is an attempt at making the code work for you - see if this hits the spot. Note that all I really did was change the type of `tempString` and `storeSecondFileStuff`, and modified the way they were used in various function calls accordingly. I did not attempt to compile / run because of the complexity of the other files involved - but this should help a bit:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Incorrect arguments, please specify 2 files to be read\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    FILE *secondFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (file == 0 || secondFile == 0) {
        printf("Could not open a file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int numDataLines2;
    int numDataLines;
    int hashTableSize;
    //First line of first file gives number of lines in file and 
    //size of hash table to be made
    if(fscanf(file, "%d%d", &numDataLines, &hashTableSize) < 2) {
        printf("Unable to parse first line of first file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    ListHndl* theHash = newHash(hashTableSize);
    int libraryID;
    char **tempString = calloc(numDataLines,sizeof(char*));  // <<< ARRAY of pointers
    char lineHolder[129];
    //discard the new line which always shows up
    fgets(lineHolder, 128, file);
    for(int i = 0; i < numDataLines; i++) {
        //Gets the whole line to be scanned with sscanf
        fgets(lineHolder, 128, file);
        tempString[i] = calloc(1, 41 * sizeof(char)); // <<< space for this string
        //If the line consists of just a newline char, continue
        if(strcmp(lineHolder, "\n") == 0 ) {
            continue;
        }
        //Scans the line retrieved from fgets and placed in lineHolder
        if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%d, %40[^\n]", &libraryID, tempString[i]) < 0){ // <<< changed
            printf("Unable to parse line %d of first file\n",i+2);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        insert(libraryID, tempString[i], hashTableSize, theHash); // <<< changed
    }
    char String[41];
    fgets(String, 40, secondFile);
    numDataLines2 = atoi(String);
    char **storeSecondFileStuff = calloc(numDataLines2, sizeof(char*)); // changed: again char **
    for(int i = 0; i< numDataLines2; i++) {
        fgets(lineHolder, 128, secondFile);
        storeSecondFileStuff[i] = calloc(1, 41 * sizeof(char));
        if(strcmp(lineHolder, "\n") == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%40[^\n]",storeSecondFileStuff[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Unable to parse line %d of second file\n",i+2);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        lookup(theHash, storeSecondFileStuff[i], hashTableSize); // <<<< changed
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(file);
    fclose(secondFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I changed it to < 2 and you were right, it gave me an error on the first line it read. How would you suggest I fix it?

Comment: Actually, I changed the line ~16 lines down mistakenly, `if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%40[^\n]",&storeSecondFileStuff[i]) == 0)` and that made the error. I changed the line you said but I didn't get any errors from it. The line you are talking about reads in text in the form of `int, booktitle' ie 12345, Othello.

Comment: See updated answer. The way you are saving the data with an offset relative to your string really bothers me. I'm having a hard time understanding what you meant to do - but whatever it is, you're not doing it.

Comment: I had `&tempString[i]` because I am passing the pointer to that memory to be stored in my Hash table and I don't want it to be overwritten. I changed the `==0` from  `if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%d, %40[^\n]", &libraryID,&tempString[i]) == 0)` to ` < 2`. What is bothering you? Also, I don't have any errors or returns, code just doesn't print what it should.

Comment: What is bothering me is that you didn't allocate enough space for all the strings - if indeed you didn't want to overwrite, then you need to allocate an array of pointers, and allocate memory separately for each pointer.

Comment: It should be the right size,right? numDataLines is the number of strings to expect and each string is at most 40 chars so calloc(numDataLines,41*sizeof(char)); should be fine I think.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was too quick in my conclusion (you are allocating enough memory) - but you are using the wrong way to point to the individual elements. I have attempted to point out in edited answer how to fix this. See if it works.

Comment: I get a seg fault now. I put a print before and after `if(sscanf(lineHolder, "%d, %40[^\n]", &libraryID, tempString[i]) < 0){ // <<< changed` and only the print before that line is executed.

Comment: Sorry - without being able to compile this I left an obvious issue that could generate segfault. See if latest update is better?

Comment: It's getting there! It's only printing one item per list but the item is correct.

Comment: Put some printf statements around the `insert` and `lookup` calls. Are you calling them more than once?

Comment: I found my problem, I had a `search` function which compared two strings stored as `void *` variables using `==`. I cast them to `char *` and then used `strcmp` and it worked! Thanks a million, I really appreciate it!